# DataTables exporting PDF/Excel with footnotes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a series of HTML tables that have the class `.custom-table`. This applies the DataTables library to them to give them all the same options.

I am trying to get the current table element using jQuery inside the Buttons > Customize function for both PDF/Excel if possible. With this I am then trying to get the matching (nearby) `.table-footnotes` list. I then want to cycle those list elements inside of the Customize function and append them to the PDF/Excel file after the table so I can effectively have all the corresponding footnotes on the exported files as are shown in the HTML.

```
<table class='custom-table table display'>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Column Heading 1</td>
    <td>Column Heading 1</td>
    <td>Column Heading 1</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Column content row 1</td>
    <td>Column content row 1</td>
    <td>Column content row 1</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<ul class='table-footnotes'>
 <li>1. footnote 1</li>
 <li>2. footnote 2</li>
 <li>3. footnote 3</li>
</ul>

$('table.custom-table').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        searching: false,
        ordering: true,
        "order": [],
        responsive: false,
        dom: 'B<"clear">rt',
        "columnDefs": [
            { "name": "My column title", "targets": 0, "className": "helper" }
        ],
        buttons: [

            {
                text: 'Show/Hide Table',
                className: 'b-toggle toggle-table helper',
                titleAttr: 'Show and Hide the table of data by clicking \"Show/Hide Table\"\ncopy to clipboard by clicking \"Copy\"\nor copy to Excel by clicking \"Excel\"'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                className: 'b-pdf helper',
                title: 'Table Title',
                messageBottom: 'Table Source',
                footer: true,
                orientation: 'landscape',
                customize: function (doc) {
                    doc['content'].push("helloooooo");
                }
            },{
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                className: 'b-html helper',
                title: 'Excel Title',
                messageBottom: 'Excel Source',
                footer: true
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Were you able to find any solution? I'm trying to achieve something similar